# figure out how many circular frames fit on screen xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid-layout

I want to create a grid with circular frames according to the number of students in a class. i want to display them i a way that the number of frames in each column fit the screen and i'll have rows added accordingly, so i tried to do something like this as a trial:

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="stdprofiles.MainPage">

    <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Grid x:Name="thislayout" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20,20" >

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs:

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var width = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
            var height = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
      
            double nbofcolumns = width / 150;
        
            double nbofrows = 10 / nbofcolumns;
            double ans = nbofcolumns * nbofrows;
           
            for (int i = 0; i < nbofcolumns-1; i++)
            {
                thislayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 100 });
            }
           
            for (int j=0;j< nbofrows+1; j++)
            {
                thislayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 100 });
            }
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                
                SwipeItem delete = new SwipeItem
                {
                  
                    IconImageSource="deleteic.png",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
                };
                List<SwipeItem> swipeItems = new List<SwipeItem>() { delete };
               
                Frame circleImageFrame = new Frame
                {
                    ClassId=i.ToString(),
                    Margin = 10,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    CornerRadius = 50,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    WidthRequest = 100,
                    IsClippedToBounds = true,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("user_profile.png"),
                        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                        Margin = -20,
                        HeightRequest = 100,
                        WidthRequest = 100
                    }
                };
                SwipeView swipe = new SwipeView
                {
                    TopItems = new SwipeItems(swipeItems),
                    Content=circleImageFrame
                };
                thislayout.Children.Add(swipe, i%(int)nbofcolumns, i/(int)nbofcolumns);
                delete.Invoked += delegate
                {
                    thislayout.Children.Remove(swipe);
                };
               
            }
}
```

the point is that i got the width of my phone screen then divided it by 150 because i specified that i want my column's width to be 100. the thing is that it's not working, the number of columns obtained do not fit the screen like i got 7 columns and only 4 columns fit the rest do not appear and so i didn't get correct number of rows. another thing surprised me is that when i tried displaying the width obtained I got 1080 (for my phone) but when I used a tablet I got 800 though my tablet I bigger than my phone. how come? something seems odd and I don't know what it is. any suggestions?

Comment: This works fine for me.  Are you accounting for the ColumnnSpacing property of the Grid?  What about the padding and margin of all the nested elements in each cell?  I'd suggest you get the basic layout working using a single element (Label, image, etc) for each cell, then once that is working start building the more complex layout.

Comment: *"displaying the width obtained I got 1080 (for my phone) but when I used a tablet I got 800"* - Your phone has a higher density of pixels. `DisplayInfo.Width` is measured in screen pixels. Divide it by `Density` to get number of "Device-Independent Pixels" (each 1/160 inch), which is what Xamarin Forms uses to measure things. If phone Density is `2`, then its width in DIPs is 1080/2 = `540`.